# Get error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at second time.....Android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

When i run my app second time then it give this error. If i clean my project then it run properly. and also I start new emulator then my app run but it not run consecutive run.

> null java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
>   com.warriorpoint.androidxmlsimple.SplashActivity.loadFeed(SplashActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.warriorpoint.androidxmlsimple.SplashActivity.access$0(SplashActivity.java:106)

my code is here

```
    private void loadFeed(){
        try{
            BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
            messages = parser.parse();
            titles = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            description = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            link = new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            arrays=new String[messages.size()][];

            final List<String> imageURL=new ArrayList<String>(1);
            imageURLAmit=new ArrayList<String>(messages.size());
            for (com.warriorpoint.androidxmlsimple.Message msg : messages){

                Spanned title=Html.fromHtml(msg.getTitle());
                titles.add(title.toString());
                link.add(msg.getLink().toString());
                Spanned data=Html.fromHtml(msg.getDescription(),new ImageGetter() {

                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            imageURL.add(source);
                        return null;
                    }
                },null);

                if(imageURL.size()!=0){
                    imageURLAmit.add(imageURL.get(0));                  

                }else{
                    imageURLAmit.add("http://blog.kevinlearynet.netdna-cdn.com/files/applausemeter-300x200.jpg");
                }
                System.out.println("Position b4 loop : "+position);
                int j;
                arrays[position]=imageURL.toArray(new String[imageURL.size()]);
                System.out.println("2D array colomn length : "+arrays[position].length);
                position++;
                System.out.println("Position afeter loop : "+position);
                imageURL.clear();           
                description.add( data.toString());
                System.out.println("End addition");
            }
            System.out.println("Final Image URL lenght : "+imageURL.size());


        } catch (Throwable t){
            Log.e("AndroidNews",t.getMessage(),t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line does the exception point to?

Comment: arrays[position]=imageURL.toArray(new String[imageURL.size()]);

Comment: I'm guessing that you don't clear position between each time, instead you keep increasing position

Comment: @zyber....then how can do this please tell me.

Comment: in the end of your function `loadFeed()` you just call `position = 0;`

Comment: @zyber....thanxx man it work..thanku so much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `position` is 0 the first time but it will be 1 the second time. If your array is of size 1, the second run will throw the exception you get.